# On the construction of Soergel bimodules

Tags: polynomials, representation-theory, lie-algebras, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

I have a question concerning §3 of this [article by Soergel](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403496) (German). Consider a polynomial ring $R=k[x,y]$ where the symmetric group $S_2=\langle s\rangle$ acts by exchanging indeterminates

$$s\colon x\rightleftarrows y.$$

Denote the invariants by $R^s=k[x+y, xy]$ and let $\alpha_s = x-y. $ It is known that $R\cong R^s\oplus \alpha_s R^s$ as $R^s$-module. Consider the modules 
$$\begin{aligned}R⊗_{R^s} R &= R⊗_k R / (a⊗1-1⊗a)_{a∈R^s},\\
D_s &= R⊗_k R /\underbrace{(sa⊗1-1⊗a)_{a∈R}}_{=: I_s}\:\underbrace{(a⊗1-1⊗a)_{a∈R}}_{=: I_e}.\end{aligned}$$

**Claim:** There is an isomorphism $R⊗_{R^s} R \to D_s$; supposedly a homogeneous map.

**Hints:**

- The above decomposition $R\cong R^s\oplus \alpha_s R^s$,
- the short exact sequence
  $$ 0\to R⊗_k R /I_s \xrightarrow{\alpha_s⊗1-1⊗\alpha_s} R⊗_k R /I_sI_e\to  R⊗_k R /I_e \to 0,$$
- If one sees that the desired map is surjective, the ismorphism follows from a graded rank argument.

**Question:** I do not know how to see that there is a map at all. What is it?

Comment: Isn't the last $I_e$ in your short exact sequence a typo for $R\otimes_k R/I_e$? I think you should then argue that the s.e.s. is split over $R^s$ and that the first and last terms identify with $R$. That will give you the correct degrees: $R\otimes_{R^s} R$ should be generated as an $R^s$ module in degrees 0,1,1,2, which is the same as the direct sum of an $R$ (from $R\otimes_k R/I_e$, degrees 0,1) and $R$ shifted up by 1 ($R\otimes_k R/I_s$ multiplied by $\alpha_s\otimes 1-1\otimes\alpha_s$, so degrees 1,2).

Comment: @m_t_ Yes, that was I typo, thanks. I agree that this sequence splits over $R^s$. If I understand you correctly, your argument shows that, if there is a surjection as claimed, then it is an iso. 

However, I do not see *that there is* a map $R⊗_{R^s} R\to D_s$ of $R$-$R$-bimodules.

Comment: Right, but you can use that knowledge to manufacture the map $R\otimes_{R^s} R \to D_s$. You know $R\otimes _{R^s}R$ is free over $R^s$ on $1\otimes 1, 1\otimes \alpha, \alpha \otimes 1, \alpha\otimes \alpha$, and you know from the s.e.s. that $D_s$ is free on $\alpha\otimes 1-1\otimes \alpha, (x\otimes 1-1\otimes x)(\alpha\otimes 1-1\otimes \alpha), 1\otimes 1, \alpha \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \alpha$, so map generators to (nice linear combinations of) generators.

Comment: @m_t_ Okay, I see I can map $1⊗1↦1⊗1$, $⊗1↦\frac 12\bigl[(⊗1-1⊗)+(⊗1+1⊗)\bigr]$. However, I do not see the linear combination for $⊗$. Maybe too blind?