# Indecomposable Soergel bimodules for $S_3$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510578/on-the-construction-of-soergel-bimodules). Consider $R=k[x,y,z]$ with an action of the symmetric group $S_3$ by exchanging variables $s:x\rightleftarrows y$ and $t: t \rightleftarrows z$. Define the $R$-$R$-bimodule $R_s = R⊗_{R^s} R$ for $R^s=[x+y, xy, z]$ the invariants under $s$, and similarly define $R_t$.

**Claim:** in Example 2.9, [this lecture](https://web.northeastern.edu/iloseu/RT/RT11.pdf) claims that the  bimodule $R⊗_{R^s} R⊗_{R^t} R⊗_{R^s} R$ decomposes into indecomposable bimodules as

$$ \bigl(R⊗_{R^{s,t}} R\bigr) ⊕ \bigr(R⊗_{R^t} R\bigr).$$

**Question:** I know that for arbitrary Coxeter groups, it is cumbersome to find indecomposable Soergel bimodules. However, for $S_3$, there should be some easy argument, shouldn't it? How can this claim be easily justified?

Comment: Have you written up how $R$ decomposes as an $R^s$-module and as an $R^s-R^t$-bimodule?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft As an $R^s$-module, we have $R\cong R^s⊕\alpha_s R^s$ where $\alpha_s = x-y$. But how does it decompose as $R^s$-$R^t$-bimodule? There should be a decomposition $(1⊕\alpha_s⊕\alpha_t⊕\alpha_s\alpha_t)R^{s,t}$ as $R^{s,t}$-bimodules. But as $R^s$-$R^t$-bimodule, isn't it indecomposable?

Comment: Actually, I seem to have forgotten how the argument goes. I will need to look closer at it tomorrow. I think this particular case is gone through in decent detail in https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00039

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah, so my decomposition is totally wrong. Instead, $R=⨁_{w∈S_3} \alpha_w R^{s,t}$. Does this make sense? What is $\alpha_w$ supposed to be for $w$ not a reflection?